# Eclipse not responding after ADT update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just updated to ADT (20.0.1) a couple of hours ago using Help->Check For Updates and now eclipse goes into the `not responding` mode with the spinning beach ball as soon as I launch eclipse. All I can see is a message in the status bar which reads `DDMS post-create init`.

Is anyone else seeing this? Are there logs somewhere I could look to get more information about this failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adage - when nothing works, reboot! worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this problem, As far as my experience was concerned it was due to the presence of the file .lock in the .metadata folder in workspace.

I don't know if you will get solution or not but close the eclipse and deleting the .metadata.lock file from workspace. try this hopefully work for you.